# hack php vs database and password obfuscation

Tags: security, hash, salt

I have no view about how much percent of hacks are breaking into codes and how much percent is breaking into database. but if my guess is true and breaking into php codes is harder than hijacking database, would it  increase security by obfuscating hashed password inside database?

in most of cases that I have seen:

```
DB_hash = bcrypt(real_password.salt);
```

why not changing it?

```
DB_hash = bcrypt(salt.real_password);
```

or even if I go further:

```
DB_hash = strrev( bcrypt(salt_last_five_char.real_password.rest_of_salt) );
```

the hacker does not know my php code. even if he knows my database, how to test his attack?

would it help increasing my security?

thanks

Comment: You must not do any of that.  SHA1 is not secure.  Use bcrypt.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's called "security by obscurity" which means that you're mistakenly relying on the implementation to protect your data, rather than a strong algorithm.   As soon as someone who has your hashes and salts figures out what you're doing you're back to the strength of the algorithm alone.

As SLaks mentioned in the comments, SHA-1 is not a good algorithm for password hashing.   Don't worry about messing about with the salts, just use a good random salt and a better algorithm, such as bcrypt.

Comment: how about bcrypt+obfuscation? do you still reject that?

Comment: @sishma I personally wouldn't advise it.  It's additional complexity which is of itself a potential security issue.   I'd stick with the simplest solution that works, which is picking an algorithm that is computationally resistant to brute-force hash cracking.

Comment: @sishma that would be [rolling your own crypto](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/20774) which is bad. It's more likely that you will make a mistake somewhere and weaken the security than that you actually make it more secure.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is to add a server-side secret. If done correctly this can indeed protect weak passwords, if the attacker has access to the database, but not to the code (this is typical for SQL-injection).

Adding the server-side secret can either be done adding a pepper before hashing, or even better by encrypting the hash-value with a server-side key before storing it to the database. What i would *not* recommend, is to obfuscate the hashing process, in your example the secret is the algorithm and not a key.